# tikzpicture cropped from `.dvi` when used in matplotlib.plt.text()

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tikz

*Disclaimer: I fully understand that the use of `text.latex.preamble` in rcparams is not officially supported by matploltib.*

*Note: the same question was posted [on the matplotlib discourse "Community" page](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/use-tikzpicture-in-plt-text-with-text-usetex-true/22249). I re-post it here to reach, hopefully, a wider "LaTeX/tikz audience".*

Dear hive mind,

I need/want to use the `tikz` [LaTeX package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to draw symbols in matplotlib `plt.text()` calls. It all works smoothly (in the sense that I get no LaTeX/matplotlib errors) ... except that no symbols are actually drawn on the figures ?!

Here is a MWE:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('./latex.mplstyle')

plt.close(1)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.text(0.5, 0.7, r'This is regular text', ha='center', va='center')
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, r'$\rightarrow$ \begin{tikzpicture}\draw [thick] (0,0) circle [radius=2ex];\end{tikzpicture}', ha='center', va='center')
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

The content of `latex.mplstyle` is:

```
text.usetex: True
text.latex.preamble: \usepackage{tikz}
```

The output looks like that:

[image: demo plot]

**Problem: there should be a circle to the right of the arrow.**

So what could matplotlib be doing differently compared to `pdflatex` that returns the following image:

[image: LaTeX demo]

when processing the following (same) LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\rightarrow$ \begin{tikzpicture}\draw [thick] (0,0) circle [radius=2ex];\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `tikz` package is definitely being loaded correctly, as the `\tikzpicture` command does not raise any error when *compiling* the matplotlib figure.

*Side-note 1: as far as I can tell, the same behavior implies that symbols from the `tikzsymbols` LaTeX package do not appear either in `plt.text()` calls.*

*Side-note 2: I evidently need to draw more (but not THAT much more) than a circle with `tikz` ... That's just the MWE!*

**Edit (after some digging thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggestions)**

It turns out that the `.dvi` files generated by LaTeX look as expected. However, these seemingly get cropped before being ingested by the matplotlib figure. Whatever is doing this cropping does not seem aware of the `tikzpicture` existence. Here's a picture with what I see in the `.dvi`, on-screen, in the `.png`, and in the `.pdf` from matplotlib:

[image]

So the question becomes:

**What mechanism is responsible for inserting the LaTeX `.dvi` inside the matplotlib figure, and why isn't it aware of the `\tikzpicture` existence ?**

and, possibly:

**Could I put the `\tikzpicture` inside some sort of LaTeX bounding box to have it become visible to matplotlib ?**

Comment: I did hesitate posting this to the [TeX StackExchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), but opted for this location instead, in view of the mixed LaTeX-Python nature of the question.

Comment: Can you access the tex .log file from matplotlib running your code?  I don't think this has to do with multiple compilations. Your tikz code does not have overlays or anything else which would require multiple passes.

Comment: Is there any way to tell matplotlib to use some vector format like pdf instead? Pixel formats are not really good for graphs.

Comment: Can you share the .dvi file?

Comment: Here is a download link for the .dvi, with 30 days validity: https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/1e57ba45-5e6c-443b-be63-6c0de3bc21b1

Comment: Thanks! The dvi looks fine. If I use tools like `dvipdf` to convert it to pdf, the circle shows up ... my guess would be that whatever method matplotlib uses for the conversion might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*See [this Matplotlib's discourse question](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/tikzpicture-cropped-from-dvi-before-ingestion-in-figure-via-plt-text/22249/5) for the full thread leading to the following answer*

**Cause:**
Matplotlib requires font metrics like the baseline, ascends and descends to include text. The `\tikzpicture` does not provide any, and so it is not taken into account in the crop of the dvi.

**Solution/work-around:**
Use the `pgf` backend to export the figure to `pdf` and/or `png` format, i.e.: `plt.savefig(..., backend='pgf')`

This method can also successfully handle the inclusion of items from the `tiksymbols` LaTeX package. However, it does not allow to display these elements on-screen.